# Custom errors and repetition of code in Back-end Typescript

Tags: typescript, backend

I am implementing data validation and sanitization in my Branch class, but I think there is too much repetition in my code and I think that maybe I am using custom errors excessively, because I am making one custom error for EACH situation.

I would like some sugestions of how to follow the DRY principle in this code and how can I make reusable custom errors.

```js
import {Column, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";
import {SystemModule} from "../../enums/SystemModule.enum";
import {Environment} from "../Environment.entity";
import {ZipCode} from "../../value-objects/ZipCode/ZipCode.value-object";
import {Cnpj} from "../../value-objects/Cnpj/Cnpj.value-object";
import {NameLengthCannotBeZeroException} from "./exceptions/NameLengthCannotBeZero.exception";
import {NameLengthCannotBeAbove200Exception} from "./exceptions/NameLengthCannotBeAbove200.exception";
import {StreetAddressLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception} from "./exceptions/StreetAddressLengthCannotBeAbove50.exception";
import {StreetNumberCannotBeLowerOrEqualTo0Exception} from "./exceptions/StreetNumberCannotBeLowerOrEqualTo0.exception";
import {
    StreetComplementLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception
} from "./exceptions/StreetComplementLengthCannotBeAbove50.exception";
import {NeighborhoodLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception} from "./exceptions/NeighborhoodLengthCannotBeAbove50.exception";
import {CityLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception} from "./exceptions/CityLengthCannotBeAbove50.exception";
import {StateLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception} from "./exceptions/StateLengthCannotBeAbove50.exception";
import {CountryLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception} from "./exceptions/CountryLengthCannotBeAbove50.exception";




@Entity("branches")
export class Branch {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column("boolean")
    active!: boolean;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 200})
    name!: string;

    @Column({type: "timestamptz", name: "created_at"})
    createdAt!: Date;

    @Column({type: "text", name: "created_by", nullable: true})
    createdBy!: string | null;

    @Column({type: "enum", name: "created_from", enum: SystemModule})
    createdFrom!: SystemModule;

    @Column({type: "timestamptz", name: "updated_at"})
    updatedAt!: Date;

    @Column({type: "text", name: "updated_by", nullable: true})
    updatedBy!: string | null;

    @Column({type: "enum", name: "updated_from", enum: SystemModule})
    updatedFrom!: SystemModule;

    @ManyToOne(() => Environment, (environment) => environment.id)
    environment!: Environment;

    @Column({type: "text", nullable: true, name: "report_logo"})
    reportLogo!: string | null;

    @Column({type: "text", name: "report_final_message"})
    reportFinalMessage!: string;

    @Column({
        type: "char",
        length: 14,
        transformer: {
            from: (value: string) => new Cnpj(value),
            to: (value: Cnpj) => value.cnpj
        }
    })
    cnpj!: Cnpj;

    @Column("float")
    latitude!: number;

    @Column("float")
    longitude!: number;

    @Column({
        type: "char",
        length: 8,
        name: "zip_code",
        transformer: {
            from: (value: string) => new ZipCode(value),
            to: (value: ZipCode) => value.zipCode
        }
    })
    zipCode!: ZipCode;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 150, name: "street_address"})
    streetAddress!: string;

    @Column({type: "integer", nullable: true, name: "street_number"})
    streetNumber!: number | null;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 50, name: "street_complement"})
    streetComplement!: string;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 50})
    neighborhood!: string;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 50})
    city!: string;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 50})
    state!: string;

    @Column({type: "varchar", length: 50})
    country!: string;



    private static sanitizeName(name: string) {
        return name
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateName(name: string) {
        if (name.length === 0)
            throw new NameLengthCannotBeZeroException();

        if (name.length > 200)
            throw new NameLengthCannotBeAbove200Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeStreetAddress(streetAddress: string) {
        return streetAddress
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateStreetAddress(streetAddress: string) {
        if (streetAddress.length > 50)
            throw new StreetAddressLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeStreetNumber(streetNumber: number | null) {
        return streetNumber === null ? streetNumber : Math.floor(streetNumber)
    }

    private static validateStreetNumber(streetNumber: number | null) {
        if (streetNumber !== null && streetNumber <= 0)
            throw new StreetNumberCannotBeLowerOrEqualTo0Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeStreetComplement(streetComplement: string) {
        return streetComplement
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateStreetComplement(streetComplement: string) {
        if (streetComplement.length > 50)
            throw new StreetComplementLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeNeighborhood(neighborhood: string) {
        return neighborhood
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateNeighborhood(neighborhood: string) {
        if (neighborhood.length > 50)
            throw new NeighborhoodLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeCity(city: string) {
        return city
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateCity(city: string) {
        if (city.length > 50)
            throw new CityLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeState(state: string) {
        return state
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateState(state: string) {
        if (state.length > 50)
            throw new StateLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception();
    }


    private static sanitizeCountry(country: string) {
        return country
            .split("\n")[0]
            .replace(/^[\r\t\f ]+|[\r\t\f ]+$/g, "")
            .replace(/[\t\f ]+/g, " ");
    }

    private static validateCountry(country: string) {
        if (country.length > 50)
            throw new CountryLengthCannotBeAbove50Exception();
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks fine to me. You may not need custom errors for each situation if you're not handling every error individually. e.g.: a ValidationError and custom message may be fine, but it also doesn't hurt. It does look a bit bulky, but that's also what you get with TypeORM

Answer (score 0):

> I would like some sugestions of how to follow the DRY principle in this code and how can I make reusable custom errors.

The level of granularity is a bit arbitrary, what works better in your case, but typically you'd have a type of exception for each *class* of things that can go wrong (e.g. ident/auth errors vs domain/data errors vs external service errors, etc., and possibly subclasses of those, if there are many cases: again, what is relevant and there is not a single way to do it, it should rather reflect your functionality and architecture), and with an *error code* or similar among the details of the exception that e.g. maps to a message (or message template) table... (as for example HTTP errors or DB errors work).